# Android: get my location from GoogleMap instance

Tags: android, location

My app does next steps:

1.Shows googleMap in mapView

2.Gets location using locationManager

requestLocationUpdates() and animate map zooming on my location. [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and [Fused location provider](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html) explain how to get location from different providers, choose the most accurate and so on. But I see that map instance (with my location enabled) is already doing this, which means doing this in my code is redundant. I definitely don't need result that are newer or more accurate than those the map instance has.

I prefer not to use deprecated OnMyLocationChangeListener.

Is there any way to get location that is currently displayed on map as my location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GoogleMap.getMyLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()) for this.

Note that this method is deprecated and the suggested alternative is to get a location yourself via FusedLocationProvider.

Also note that location tracking with the FusedLocationProvider is shared between apps, if multiple apps are requesting locations, it is only done once and then send to all apps. This means that your app would not be draining more battery if another app such as Google Maps was already requesting location updates.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that maps also use fusedLocationProvider